# How to configure a VPS to be a standalone DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

I have CentOS based VPS and i currently run a web based application on it. recently i bought a domain name and wanted to map this name to my vps. I thought that after buying the domain they take care of DNS issues and mapping the IP to name is a matter of point and shoot.

but it seems that I have to install the DNS server on my own VPS for the domain name to be resolved. I surfed the web and got the overall gist of what i should do. I configured the necessary files but i think parts of it are incorrect ( or I have overlooked a step ). the following are the steps I did:

- Installed BIND
- configured named.conf
- created zone files (forward and reverse lookup)
- configured the network adapter ( added dns2=127.0.0.1 and domain name
  "example.ir")
- firewall configurations

to make a long story short, here is my example.ir.zone file's content:

```
$ORIGIN examle.ir.
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     ns2.example.ir.  hostmaster.example.ir. (
        199609203       ; Serial
        28800   ; Refresh
        3600    ; Retry
        604800  ; Expire
        86400 )  ; Minimum TTL

        IN      NS      ns2.example.ir.

        IN      MX      10      mail.example.ir.

        IN      A       127.0.0.1

ns2     IN      A       127.0.0.1

ftp     IN      A       127.0.0.1

h88-150-136-1.host.redstation.co.uk   IN      A       127.0.0.1

mail    IN      CNAME   h88-150-136-1.host.redstation.co.uk

www     IN      CNAME   h88-150-136-1.host.redstation.co.uk`
```

Note that I have started named service without problem, but can only see my domain name from inside the vps, NOT outside ...

This may seem newbish; but can anyone hint me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong?!

Comment: I would suggest to transfer the domain to another provider who offers DNS services and allows you to edit the records e.g. from a web interface. They will manage this for you and also offer the necessary redundancy.

Comment: @SvW I know that some providers offer DNS services ... but since I had this vps from the beginning and had done quite a lot of configuration done, I'd rather continue with my current VPS ...

Comment: I didn't say to transfer the VPS, just the domain. There are many providers/registrars offering just domain registration and DNS services.

Comment: @SvW ... aha, OK I will keep that in mind and search for the proper provider in the meanwhile ... thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: in bind shorthand hostnames not ending in a `.` are appended with the zone name.

If your zone is `example.ir` the `mail` entry is shorthand for `mail.example.ir.` and your CNAME records actually point to `h88-150-136-1.host.redstation.co.uk.example.ir.`

Unless you were trying to mask your ip-address by using 127.0.0.1 in most cases you do not point DNS records to localhost, but to a routable ip-address, such as `88.150.136.1` (which appears the ip-address for h88-150-136-1.host.redstation.co.uk.)

Comment: I guessed that my problem would be the IP configuration ... I now changed the configuration as you said ... but I wonder how I can test the credibility of these changes ...

Comment: The commandline tool to test DNS is `dig` or use one of the online chekers like http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

Comment: I used the tool you mentioned and it gave back this answer `Loop detected! We were referred back to '88.150.136.1'` ... but still I can not ping my domain.